# Resolve Javascript Conflicts / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sqlbuddy

I am trying to add jQuery to the PHP of SQLBuddy and am getting some conflicts. If I just include jQuery, the rest of the program stops functioning and doesn't pull the tables / databases.

If I use the jQuery noConflict function, everything works, but I can't use any jQuery selectors. Is there a way to merge 2 libraries that will show you where there are 2 functions with the same name and prompt you to rename one of them?

Comment: Sounds like you're not using `noConflict` correctly. Please show your code, we can't tell what you're doing wrong without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`noConflict` returns a reference to the jquery function, so you should just be able to assign the return value to a variable and use that instead of `$` or `jquery`. Like so:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
// $j is now an alias to the jQuery function; creating the new alias is optional.

$j(document).ready(function() {
    $j( "div" ).hide();
});
```

see:
http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

Comment: Thank you, I didn't see the `var $j =` in the example I was following before.